# Perform file handling operation, access to cmd, databases and OS details if Remote desktop is provided

Tags: c#, windows, remote-access

When I have a remote desktop access to a sever ie administrator access, how can I perform file handling operations, run commands on cmd, access sql server databases and get system details?

What I want to know is there any windows service available or do I have to install application there that does it for us.

I like to use C#.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me.. Is this about programming?

Comment: yes it is about programming .

Comment: its like controlling some features of server remotely, using c# and consider a fact that we have a remote desktop credentials